# Solve the given equation. sin^2 θ − 3 sin θ − 4 = 0

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My answer is $\pi/2 + 2k \pi$ and $5\pi/2 + 2k \pi$. Webassign is marking me wrong however. Is it right?

Comment: Is that $\sin^2(\theta)$ or $\sin(2\theta)$? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Did you try plugging those into the equation to see if they are actually solutions? (They aren't). Also, did you try checking your answer with WolframAlpha? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%282x%29-3sin%28x%29-4+%3D+0

Comment: Why are you frustrated with Maths ? I think you need a hug from a Panda.

Comment: sin^2θ − 3 sin θ − 4 = 0

Comment: I want to answer the question but I am on my tab and I have fat fingers..

Comment: No, it is not correct. Just compute the expression at $\pi/2$ to see why.

Comment: And apart from the fact that your two solutions are both wrong, they are actually both the same...

Comment: Note as well that your two answers are not actually distinct since $5\pi/2+2\pi \cdot 0 = \pi/2 + 2\pi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's solve it by factoring: $0 = \sin^2 \theta - 3\sin \theta - 4 = (\sin \theta - 4)(\sin \theta + 1)$

Thus, we need either $\sin \theta = 4$ (no solutions) or $\sin \theta = -1$.

Now, can you solve $\sin \theta = -1$? (note the negative sign)

Comment: pi/2 is that right, thus pi/2 +2kpi

Comment: $\sin \dfrac{\pi}{2} = +1$ not $-1$. Try again.

Comment: Okay. 3pi/2 +2kpi. Is that right?

Comment: yes (ignore what I said about another group, there isn't in this case)

Answer (score 1):

The equation is quadratic in $\sin \theta$. Using the quadratic formula, we get: $$\sin \theta = \frac{3 + \sqrt{9+16}}{2} = 4 \quad \mbox{or} \quad \sin \theta = \frac{3 - \sqrt{9+16}}{2} = -1$$
The first possibility is absurd. Which values of $\theta$ give $\sin \theta = -1$?